# RSpec, Rails 6 and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

Currently have a Rails 6 project with Devise.  Trying to build some RSpec tests (I'm just learning RSpec).  The user authentication seems to be causing this problem.  This error occurs when running the RSPec test for a view.

Failure/Error: <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id%>

```
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
   Make sure that your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack.
   If you are seeing this on one of your tests, ensure that your tests are either executing the Rails middleware stack or that your tests are using the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module to inject the `request.env['warden']` object for you.
 # ./app/views/agent_quotes/edit.html.erb:38:in `block in _app_views_agent_quotes_edit_html_erb___1192221995643336498_23640'
 # ./app/views/agent_quotes/edit.html.erb:35:in `_app_views_agent_quotes_edit_html_erb___1192221995643336498_23640'
 # ./spec/views/agent_quotes/edit.html.erb_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
 # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # Devise::MissingWarden:
 #   Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
 #   Make sure that your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack.
 #   If you are seeing this on one of your tests, ensure that your tests are either executing the Rails middleware stack or that your tests are using the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module to inject the `request.env['warden']` object for you.
 #   ./app/views/agent_quotes/edit.html.erb:38:in `block in _app_views_agent_quotes_edit_html_erb___1192221995643336498_23640'
```

I've searched for solutions and incorporate suggestions such as adding

config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller

and require 'spec_helper' to my rails_helper.rb file but no change.  Most of the suggestions seemed to be for earlier versions of Rails.  I'll keep looking at docs but if anyone has run into this please let me know.